# Jacoco Integration test report is not correct

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a restful api and the workflow of integration test cases is that we build the project -> Then start a tomcat using maven on a predefined port -> Deploy the built war on that tomcat instance and then maven runs the integration test cases with respect to that war. Build is succeeded only if the unit as well as integration test cases pass. I want to generate code coverage report for integration as well unit test cases. Though Jacoco is correctly generating report for unit test cases but it is not generating the correct report for integration test cases . As in all the folders are shown with zero percent coverage.

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
      <executions>
            <execution>
                  <id>default-report</id>
                  <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                  <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                  </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                  <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                  <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                        <destFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                  </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                  <id>post-unit-test</id>
                  <phase>test</phase>
                  <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
                        <append>true</append>
                  </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                  <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                  <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                  <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                        <destFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                        <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                  </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                  <id>post-integration-test</id>
                  <phase>verify</phase>
                  <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                        <includes>
                        </includes>
                        <dataFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/site/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                  </configuration>
            </execution>
      </executions>
</plugin>
```

On failsafe plugin :

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      <configuration>
            <includes>
                  <include>**/*IT.java</include>
            </includes>
            <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
            <execution>
                  <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                        <includes>
                              <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                        </includes>
                  </configuration>
            </execution>
      </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: do your ITs run? Are they executed? Does adding a <phase> to you <execution> of the failsafe plugin help? (don't see an error, so I would experiment a bit). I think the goals "integration-test" and "verify" should not run in the same phase.

Comment: Yes IT do run. but even then report is not generated properly. I will try the methods you have suggested and will update results here.

Comment: You had any progress ? I'm faced with the very same issue.

Comment: Don't you need to pass the failsafeArgLine variable to your Jetty instance ?

Comment: No I ultimately gave up this code and then used https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-jacoco?files=1 code and jacoco.exec files hence generated were used in Jenkins to display code coverage of Unit and integration test cases. Just use <build>... <goal>prepare-agent</goal>....</build> code as written and then run mvn package.